# Making email field mandatory in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

[According to Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/), 'email' field is optional. I want to change this default behaviour shipped by Django.

I have extended the model to add some custom fields, but still I am not able to override this (due to technical limitations). I saw some other questions here about related issues with the User model and they usually suggest to subclass the registration form to require the email field.

However, you cannot do that from the admin side. My application does not have a sign up form, but the users have to be added from the admin panel.

So far I have been googling for a good while and it seems that it is not possible at all or I have to re-create a whole model just to change this, which does not sound like the optimal solution for me.

Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: Could you show how does your User model look now?

Comment: You could also fool around with the built-in admin for `User` to make it require the email field. But if I were you I would just go ahead and [make your own custom user class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). It's relatively painless if you subclass `AbstractBaseUser`, and it will give you more flexibility down the line if there are other things you decide to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make the email field required, then the cleanest way is to create a custom user model that is exactly like your original user model, but with email field set as unique. Django already has a [`AbstractUser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L353) class that has what you need. You can modify your `User` model like this -

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    # your extra fields
```

After making the change Django will keep the email field required wherever you use it, even from Admin panel.

Comment: As far as I knew, abstract classes were (in brief) used to take a model as a reference and then add some additional fields. But now I have I can actually *override* fields from the parent abstract model (in this case, User) - that makes thing much much easier, so thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I also assumed that overriding isn't possible when you inherit from `AbstractUser` and I have tried this but I can't override the fields. I get the following error:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'first_name' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'`.
Would someone be able to explain this to me?

Comment: @Heyl1 AbstractUser class already has a first_name field. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L353 You cannot override it. If you want to make the first_name field required, then you can extend AbstractBaseUser and build the usermodel from scratch. Just look at the source of AbstractUser and copy everything except the field you want to change and change it.

Comment: Ok, I thought that in your comment above you said you could extend `AbstractUser` and override the fields (in the case of the topic starter 'email' and in my case both 'email', 'firstname' and 'lastname') in that model but I guess I misunderstood. Thanks!